# How to know why some transitive phrasal verbs cannot be split

Tags: phrasal-verbs, transitivity

1. What is the reason that **some transitive phrasal verbs with adverb particles cannot be split**?
   Examples: 'My brother looks after my mother.' Likewise, come across, count on, and such are other transitive phrasal verbs which cannot be split.
2. Is there a way to check why some phrasal verbs with adverb particles cannot be split OR do we have to remember them by usage experience?

Comment: I think you may have the wrong idea about particles. Detaching the phrase is not a suitable way to determine whether a particle is a preposition or an adverb. Prepositional particles can occur before between the verb and its direct object, or after the NP object. Compare this pair where "up" is a preposition in both cases: "I looked up his biography" ~ "I looked his biography up". ""Similarly with the preposition "down" ~ "He shouted down his opponent" ~ "He shouted his opponent down". The point here is that in modern grammar, items like "up" and "down" are prepositions in examples like those.

Comment: I know that, but you have the 'background' wrong, so in your example 1. the word "after" is a preposition here, not an adverb. The reason it's not a particle is that "looks" is intransitive so it cannot take an object.  Regarding your example 1. in "held up the bank" it is not the whole expression "held up" that is a verb, but just the word "held". "Up" is a separate constituent, a preposition.  Note that "held up the bank" consists of verb-prep-object.

Comment: The question is whether to take your misinformation or some valid source (Have more sources). Again, I  am not seeking your opinion on the word "up". The questions are marked.

Comment: No: that's not correct. Whether a word is an adverb or a preposition depends on the distinctive properties of the word concerned, not how it functions in a prepositional idiom.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/151464/discussion-between-billj-and-brp7).

Comment: There is a lot of coverage of this in EFL ([example: British Council](https://learnenglish.britishcouncil.org/grammar/c1-grammar/word-order-phrasal-verbs)) and there are guidelines, but there doesn't seem to be a clear rule. As to where you can look it up, try a dictionary with usage examples like Merriam-Webster.

Comment: Thanks, Stuart. I have upvoted your comment. I had that link added to my favourites when I framed this question. Would you agree with the opinion that the particles in the phrasal verbs I have given as examples are adverb particles and NOT prepositions? Many sources don't deal with that.